# Python summing up time

Tags: python, datetime

In python how do I sum up the following time?

```
 0:00:00
 0:00:15
 9:30:56
```

Comment: I presume you want to add up the differences from 0:00:00 ? ie, the deltas, rather than the actual times?

Comment: @steve: well, the deltas would add up to `9:30:56`

Comment: i am using python 2.4 and i cannot use strptime,yes i want to add up the deltas and for the above mentioned example the answer should be 9:31:11

Comment: i.e. the times given are already deltas.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As a list of strings?

```
timeList = [ '0:00:00', '0:00:15', '9:30:56' ]
totalSecs = 0
for tm in timeList:
    timeParts = [int(s) for s in tm.split(':')]
    totalSecs += (timeParts[0] * 60 + timeParts[1]) * 60 + timeParts[2]
totalSecs, sec = divmod(totalSecs, 60)
hr, min = divmod(totalSecs, 60)
print "%d:%02d:%02d" % (hr, min, sec)
```

Result:

```
9:31:11
```

Comment: +1 just for giving `divmod()` some airplay  ... pity nobody was ever brave enough to request GvR to implement `/%` and `/%=` operators ;-) ... read this and weep: `mins, secs /%= 60; hours, mins /%= 60; days, hours /%= 24`

Comment: @John: I personally find that illegible.  You have to remember which thing on the LHS is the input dividend. It also creates a case where an operator returns a tuple, which prevents chaining operations, which is the whole point of binary operators.  I find the `divmod` way a *lot* clearer.

Comment: I think is better using deltas

Answer (score 31):

It depends on the form you have these times in, for example if you already have them as `datetime.timedelta`s, then you could just sum them up:

```
>>> s = datetime.timedelta(seconds=0) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=15) + datetime.timedelta(hours=9, minutes=30, seconds=56)
>>> str(s)
'9:31:11'
```

Answer (score 31):

Using timedeltas (tested in Python 3.9):

```
import datetime

timeList = ['0:00:00', '0:00:15', '9:30:56']
mysum = datetime.timedelta()
for i in timeList:
    (h, m, s) = i.split(':')
    d = datetime.timedelta(hours=int(h), minutes=int(m), seconds=int(s))
    mysum += d
print(str(mysum))
```

Result:

```
9:31:11
```

Comment: Works in 2.7 too. +1 because the code is readable and intuitive

Answer (score 5):

I'm really disappointed if there is not any more pythonic solution... :(

Horrible one ->

```
timeList = [ '0:00:00', '0:00:15', '9:30:56' ]

ttt = [map(int,i.split()[-1].split(':')) for i in timeList]
seconds=reduce(lambda x,y:x+y[0]*3600+y[1]*60+y[2],ttt,0)
#seconds == 34271
```

This one looks horrible too ->

```
zero_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('0:0:0', '%H:%M:%S')
ttt=[datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%H:%M:%S')-zero_time for i in timeList]
delta=sum(ttt,zero_time)-zero_time
# delta==datetime.timedelta(0, 34271)

# str(delta)=='9:31:11' # this seems good, but 
# if we have more than 1 day we get for example str(delta)=='1 day, 1:05:22'
```

Really frustrating is also this ->

```
sum(ttt,zero_time).strftime('%H:%M:%S')  # it is only "modulo" 24 :(
```

I really like to see one-liner so, I tried to make one in python3 :P (good result but horrible look)

```
import functools
timeList = ['0:00:00','0:00:15','9:30:56','21:00:00'] # notice additional 21 hours!
sum_fnc=lambda ttt:(lambda a:'%02d:%02d:%02d' % (divmod(divmod(a,60)[0],60)+(divmod(a,60)[1],)))((lambda a:functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x+y[0]*3600+y[1]*60+y[2],a,0))((lambda a:[list(map(int,i.split()[-1].split(':'))) for i in a])(ttt)))
# sum_fnc(timeList) -> '30:40:11'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
lines = ["0:00:00", "0:00:15", "9:30:56"]
total = 0
for line in lines:
    h, m, s = map(int, line.split(":"))
    total += 3600*h + 60*m + s
print "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (total / 3600, total / 60 % 60, total % 60)
```

Comment: Ummmm this is tagged `Python` not `awk`; `3600*"0"` won't compute; you need to use `int()`; you need to test stuff before publishing it

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to add up the seconds for a total time:

```
def parse_time(s):
    hour, min, sec = s.split(':')
    try:
        hour = int(hour)
        min = int(min)
        sec = int(sec)
    except ValueError:
        # handle errors here, but this isn't a bad default to ignore errors
        return 0
    return hour * 60 * 60 + min * 60 + sec

print parse_time('0:00:00') + parse_time('0:00:15') + parse_time('9:30:56')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import timedelta

h = ['3:00:00','1:07:00', '4:00:00', '4:05:00', '4:10:00', '4:03:00']

def to_td(h):
    ho, mi, se = h.split(':')
    return timedelta(hours=int(ho), minutes=int(mi), seconds=int(se))

print(str(sum(map(to_td, h), timedelta())))

# Out[31]: 20:25:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Naive approach (without exception handling):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def sumup(*times):
    cumulative = 0
    for t in times:
        hours, minutes, seconds = t.split(":")
        cumulative += 3600 * int(hours) + 60 * int(minutes) + int(seconds)
    return cumulative

def hms(seconds):
    """Turn seconds into hh:mm:ss"""
    hours = seconds / 3600
    seconds -= 3600*hours
    minutes = seconds / 60
    seconds -= 60*minutes
    return "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (hours, minutes, seconds)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print hms(sumup(*("0:00:00", "0:00:15", "9:30:56")))
    # will print: 09:31:11
```

Answer (score 0):

Bellow is a solution using list comprehension:

```
from datetime import timedelta

def time_sum(time: List[str]) -> timedelta:
    """
    Calculates time from list of time hh:mm:ss format
    """

    return sum(
        [
            timedelta(hours=int(ms[0]), minutes=int(ms[1]), seconds=int(ms[2]))
            for t in time
            for ms in [t.split(":")]
        ],
        timedelta(),
    )
```

Example:

```
time_list = ["0:00:00", "0:00:15", "9:30:56"]
total = time_sum(time_list)
print(f"Total time: {total}")
```