# Pandas: How can I add two timestamp values?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, data-science, data-cleaning

I am trying to add more than two timestamp values and I expect to see output in minutes/seconds. How can I add two timestamps? I basically want to do: `'1995-07-01 00:00:01' + '1995-07-01 00:05:06'` and see if `total time>=60minutes`.
I tried this code: `df['timestamp'][0]+df['timestamp'][1]`. I referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780897/python-sum-up-time) but my timestamps are coming from dataframe.
Head of my dataframe column looks like this:

```html
0   1995-07-01 00:00:01
1   1995-07-01 00:00:06
2   1995-07-01 00:00:09
3   1995-07-01 00:00:09
4   1995-07-01 00:00:09
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I am getting this error: 
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'Timestamp'`

Comment: How do you expect to add two timestamps?  If you add Tuesday and Wednesday, does that make Friday?  Please show your expected output for given input.

Comment: I want to add two timestamps '1995-07-01 00:00:01' + '1995-07-01 00:59:59' to see the output like this 60minutes.

Comment: OK, so you want some sort of duration?  Duration from when?

Comment: yes, I have dataframe of IP addresses and timestamps. I want to know total duration for each IP address. I am trying to calculate this by adding all timestamp values for each unique IP address.

Comment: You missed the important part of the question.  Duration from when?

Comment: I am not trying to subtract. If you see head of my dataframe I am trying to add time values to calculate total duration.

Comment: Sigh, I will go back to my first question.  If you add Tuesday and Wednesday, does that make Friday?

Comment: No it won't make Friday. I'm trying my best to make it clear but I'm not sure what is missing to make you understand. I hope to get solution for this soon. I am stuck on it since 3 hours.

Comment: A duration always requires a subtraction if you have a timestamp.  Because a duration has a beginning and an end. You are trying to add Tuesday and Wednesday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Adding two timestamps is not supported and not logical
#Probably, you really want to add the time rather than the timestamp itself
#This is how to extract the time from the timestamp then summing it up

import datetime
import time

t = ['1995-07-01 00:00:01','1995-07-01 00:00:06','1995-07-01 00:00:09','1995-07-01 00:00:09','1995-07-01 00:00:09']
tSum = datetime.timedelta()
df = pd.DataFrame(t, columns=['timestamp'])
for i in range(len(df)):
    df['timestamp'][i] = datetime.datetime.strptime(df['timestamp'][i], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").time()
    dt=df['timestamp'][i]
    (hr, mi, sec) = (dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second)
    sum = datetime.timedelta(hours=int(hr), minutes=int(mi),seconds=int(sec))
    tSum += sum
if tSum.seconds >= 60*60:
    print("more than 1 hour")
else:
    print("less than 1 hour")
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that adding `Timestamp`s makes no sense.  What if they were on different days?  What you want are the sum of `Timedelta`s.  We can create `Timedelta`s by subtracting a common date from the whole series.  Let's subtract the minimum date.  Then sum up the `Timedelta`s.  Let `s` be your series of `Timestamps`

```
s.sub(s.dt.date.min()).sum().total_seconds()

34.0
```