# how to add hours in python? in the format below:

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

how to add hours in python?  in the format below:

```
hour1= '20:00'
hour2= '25:00' 
sum= hour1 + hour2
```

so the correct print and formatted as I want it would be:
result of the sum 45:00:00

Comment: Do you really want seconds in the output, while you don't have them in your input format?

Answer (score 0):

I just copied and edited this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28950926/18129097):

```
import datetime

# for show hours use below format
timeList = ['25:00:00', '20:00:00']
mysum = datetime.timedelta()
for i in timeList:
    (h, m, s) = i.split(':')
    d = datetime.timedelta(hours=int(h), minutes=int(m), seconds=int(s))
    mysum += d
print(str(mysum))
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'h' is not defined`. You introduced errors while copying the original answer, and didn't take the time to test the code. Note that the OP wanted hours and minutes, not minutes and seconds, and he stated that his expected output was "45:00", which you can't get by printing timedelta objects: hours over 24 get converted to days.

Comment: excuse me, edited answer: add `hours` to datetime.timedelta

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood the question but the code works. when the result gets over 24 converts to day.

Comment: You're still adding minutes and seconds instead of hours and minutes. Try it with `timeList = ['25:00:00', '20:00:00']` and see how this doesn't give the expected output. Note that the OP asked about adding *hours*, and provided an expected output in HH:MM:SS format, which seems to indicate that the inputs would be in HH:MM format.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille you right, the answer is totally wrong based on what Rafael asked. how about i delete this answer?

Comment: That's probably the thing to do in this case, there's no simple way to make use of `datetime` here... It would also probably be good to wait for the OP to answer the question about the discrepancy between his input and output format...